# Android: Is Audio Effects supported in OpenCore?

Tags: android, audio, effects, opencore

I would like to ask if audio-effects is supported in OpenCore. When we tried to set some audio effects and tried to play the audio file (supported on opencore only), it seems that the effects are not enabled.  However, when we tried to play an audio file, which is supported on stagefright only, the effects seem to be working. So we are thinking that audio-effect is not supported in opencore. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
artsylar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Opencore does not have support for Audio Effects. Neither does Stagefright.

However GingerBread version Android comes with default Audio Effects. These effects have been plugged in AudioTrack class (~ AudioSink / AudioFlinger), an internal Android c++ class. In Android Multimedia stack, an instance of AudioTrack is provided to the underlying media player. The player could be stagefright, or opencore or midi etc. In stagefright player, AudioTrack instance provided is used for audio playback. But the Opencore create its own instance of AudioTrack. Therefore audio playback using opencore stack does not have effects.

Shash316

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it depends. There's a detailed chart [here](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/opensles/index.html) of all supported of OpenSL ES on Android. I would assume OpenCore would have the same fields checked out for AudioEffect.